# How can we know the JavaScript variable from another module that this module imports?

Tags: javascript

a.js

```
import "b.js"
var globalVar = 3;
```

b.js

```
alert(globalVar);
```

It's worked. How is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure that works?  First:  there's no `import` in Javascript that loads files and Second: that variable is being declared and defined AFTER it supposedly gets called by the "imported" file, which would result in a type error of `undefined`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qc4p7/

Comment: sorry, it's just for explaination. Instead of import line, we can use  like, <script type="text/javascript" src="a.js"></script>

Comment: Oh I understand that, but you still would not get a usable result from that code because of the order they are in.

Answer (score 2):

Variables in the global scope in JavaScript are just that: *global*. There is no distinction between which file the variable was declared in, if it was declared in the global scope.

As @FelixKling mentioned in the comment there is a proposal to add modules to JavaScript in a future version which would function similar to namespaces (or packages) in other languages.

That is a very good example of why it is a very good idea to avoid using global variables.

Comment: thanks. I am accustomed with java. so it's very strange. thanks.

Comment: *"there is no concept of module"* There is, in the next ECMAScript version: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules.

Comment: @FelixKling that's interesting. I wasn't aware of that (although it is just a proposed feature at this point)